# Why doesn't WebClient honor system or user web proxy settings?

Tags: .net, proxy, webclient

I've done some testing with System.Net.WebClient with Fiddler and WireShark. I can see that even if a proxy is configured (Fiddler), WebClient doesn't use it.

WebClient's Proxy property has the correct proxy and if I examine it or call its Proxy GetProxy with the URI I'm accessing, it will return the proper proxy URI.

This seems very broken!

All the examples and questions an answers seem to say you can manually set the proxy. That's not a good solution. I want to be able to have a live WebClient active over multiple URI calls which will use a proxy when it's configured, e.g. I start with Fiddler off, do a couple of requests, turn Fiddler on, do a couple of requests, turn Fiddler back off.

Related Links:
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx
    http://www.telerik.com/fiddler
    http://www.wireshark.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can force it to use system proxy with an entry in your config file like this:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
</system.net>
```